# Returning a pointer to an array of structs

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct, malloc

Let's say I have to create an array of structs that is allocated on the heap and return a pointer that points to this array of structs.

```
typedef struct Pair {
    int x;
    int y;
} Pair;

Pair** foo(int n, int m, int length)
{
    Pair* arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        arr[i].x = n++;
        arr[i].y = m++;
    }

    return &arr;
}
```

When I compile a program containing this function, it warns me that I am returning the address of a local variable. I assume this is because the pointer is initialised within the function (i.e. on the stack), therefore it counts as a local variable.

When I compile it, ignoring this warning, and run it anyway, the program crashes when the returned pointer is accessed.

I have tried allocating the pointer dynamically:

```
Pair** ptr = malloc(sizeof(**ptr));
ptr = &arr;
...
return ptr;
```

but the program still crashes when this pointer is accessed. How can I create this array within a function and return a pointer to this array so that it can be safely accessed?

Comment: Do you need an array of structures, or an array of pointers to structures?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want an pointer to an array of structs, you can change your function signature from `Pair**` to be `Pair*`.

---

If you still want an pointer to an array of pointers, then allocate memory for a `Pair` struct for each index of `arr`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
    arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(Pair));
    ...
}
```

Instead of returning `&arr`, you can declare `arr` as

```
Pair** arr = malloc(sizeof(Pair*) * length);
```

Comment: Thank you. This clarifies what I did wrong. A follow-up question for safety: Does the change of declaration to `Pair** arr` mean that the accessing of this array of structs changes to `arr[i]->first` ?

Comment: @GabrielSaul This returns an array of pointers, not an array of structures. Is that really what you want?

Comment: If you do this, you have to change `arr[i].x = n++;` to `arr[i]->x = n++;` since `arr[i]` is a pointer.

Comment: (a) The first statement is wrong; OP’s `Pair* arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * length);` allocates memory for `length` objects of type `Pair`. (b) OP does not need to create an array of pointers. Their declaration of `foo` as returning `Pair **` is a mistake; they only need to return a `Pair *`, and they only need to allocate an array of `Pair` objects. They do not need, according to the question as stated, to create an array of pointers to `Pair` objects.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah that's what I get for skimming over the `sizeof(*arr)`.

Comment: It is not likely OP wants an array of pointers. They refer to an array of `struct`. Most likely they want a pointer to the first `struct` of an allocated array. Possibly, but less likely, they want a pointer to such a pointer. Even less likely do they want a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers to `struct`.

Comment: @Miket25: What you would place your money on is not of use to anybody in determining OP’s desires. The text of their request supplies information; they request “I have to … return a pointer that points to this array of structs.” Additionally, a person asking a question at this level is a novice; they are at the stage where students learn to use pointers for the first time, and the exercises they are given are to allocate space for an array and to return a pointer to the space.

Answer (score 4):

This array is initialized on the stack but the pointer (`arr`) is a local variable, so the caller, `main`, cannot access it. You do not need to use the address of the pointer. You can access the array with the pointer itself.

```
Pair* foo(int n, int m, int length)
{
    Pair* arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        arr[i].x = n++;
        arr[i].y = m++;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an *array* of structs, the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Pair;

static Pair* foo(int n, int m, int length)   {
    Pair* arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        arr[i].x = n++;
        arr[i].y = m++;
    }
    return arr;
}

int main(void) {
    Pair *z = foo(111, 222, 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
        printf("z[%d]= { %d, %d }\n", i, z[i].x, z[i].y);
    free(z);
    return 0;
}
```

gives the output:

```
z[0]= { 111, 222 }
z[1]= { 112, 223 }
z[2]= { 113, 224 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Because `arr` is  a local variable, it will be free when `foo` end. So you don't have access for `arr` after. To solve this you should declare array pointer in heap:

```
     Pair** foo(int n, int m, int length)
     {
           Pair ** arr = (Pair**)malloc(sizeof(Pair*));
           *arr = malloc(sizeof(Pair) * length);

           for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
               (*arr)[i].x = n++;
               (*arr)[i].y = m++;
           }

            return arr;
       }
```

Comment: @JosephQuinsey: Either `Pair **arr = malloc(sizeof *arr); *arr = malloc(sizeof **arr * length);` is correct or `Pair *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * length);` is correct. Deleting the second `malloc` and putting `length` in the first without changing it from `Pair **` to `Pair *` is incorrect. Likely the latter is desired; OP probably does not need the former.

Comment: Can you explain why? I dont understand

Comment: @LinhNguyenHuy: Deleting the second malloc and putting `length` in the first produces `Pair **arr = (Pair*)malloc(sizeof(Pair*)*length);`, which allocates space for `length` pointers to `struct`. But the question does not request an array of pointers. It requests an array of structures.

Comment: Additionally, it leaves the type mismatch; the cast is to `Pair *`, but the object being initialized has type `Pair **`.

Comment: Ya. But I think I just modify the cast to `(Pair**)`. The function requests a pointer of array so I return a pointer of array =))